# Download all CSV files from folders and subfolders with URL in R

Tags: r, csv, web-scraping, rcurl

I was trying to download the CSV files from this site: http://tiservice.hii.or.th/opendata/data_catalog/daily_rain/. These are the daily rainfall data, which were stored by year (in its own folder), and months as subfolder in each year.

[example of the folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCadw.png)

In each month folder, individual files for each weather station are available. **I want to be able to pull data from a specific station (e.g. ABRT.csv) from all the subfolders within the parent directory.**

I was able to do this with the file in my local folder like this.

```
dir("climate_data/temperature/", recursive=TRUE, full.names=TRUE, pattern="\\ABRT.csv$")
```

Is it possible to do a similar thing directly from the URL from R (or terminal, if that would be easier)?

Comment: I'd look at `rvest` for scraping the directory and file names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
eg <- expand.grid(2012:2021, 
                  c("01", "02", "03", "04","05","06", "07", "08", "09", "10","11","12"))
eg$url <- paste("http://tiservice.hii.or.th/opendata/data_catalog/daily_rain/",
                eg[,1], 
                "/", 
                paste(eg[,1], 
                      eg[,2], 
                      sep=""), 
                "/ABRT.csv", 
                sep="")
eg$dest <- paste(eg[,1], eg[,2], "ABRT.csv", sep="_")
for(i in 1:nrow(eg)){
  curl::curl_download(eg$url[1], eg$dest[1])
}
```

Comment: This works great. Thank you!